# Router v2.1 transitionTo does not work

Tags: ember.js, transition, router

I'm trying to use the new Router API ([at commit 6a165ad](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/commit/6a165adc15b54ce731e10eb296616efca6a51745)), and I have some problems.

Given this router:

```
Router.map(function(match) {
  match("/posts").to("posts", function(match) {
    match("/new").to('new', function(match) {
      match("/author").to('author');
    });
  });
});
```

I'm trying to transition to the `new` route.

**Using new.index:** `this.transitionTo('new.index')`

It works, but as you can see the route name is not really explicit (we don't even know that it's for a new post). It's consequently not a viable solution.

**Using posts.new:** `this.transitionTo('posts.new')`

I hoped it works, but an error is thrown:

> The route `posts.new` was not found.

I believed the transition to the index was made automatically, but it seems not.

**Using customized route name:**

Since the commit specified above, Ember allows custom route naming. As my previous attempt does not work, I tried to force the `new` route to be `posts.new`, but it still does not work (idem if it was `foo.new`).

It looks like its not possible to go to a customized route that has nested routes.

### TL;DR

- I'd like to transition to the `new` route (and specifying `posts`). How should it be done ?
- Before the router v2.1, I had routes that has child without `to` (i.e. `match("/posts", function(match) { ... })`), is it still working ? If so, what's the name of its children ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was actually a bug in Ember. Because `index` is implicit, you should not need to explicitly provide it.

The bug was fixed on [master](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/commit/2426cb93ef9844d96219f399577e32fd7b667597).

If you want to go to a route that has child routes, you should `transitionTo` the specified name of the route, and Ember will automatically add the `index` for you.